# What Latex font is this

Tags: stix2

I'm wondering what latex font packages is [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.04297) written in? Looks like almost the standard Latex package but mixed with STIX2.

Comment: I certainly didn't realize that it helps. Quite technical stuff.

Comment: You can download the latex source code of the article from https://arxiv.org/format/2106.04297 Then you can just look up which packages it uses.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.